# Enviar texto com Client Socket a partir de um formulário que é exibido acima de outro Form que fica sempre no topo

Tags: delphi, socket

Estou com dificuldades para enviar mensagens de texto a partir de um *Client Socket*. O formulário que envia o texto, é exibido sempre acima do formulário que permanece sempre no topo, quando `FormOnTop` não existe (não é mostrado), funciona bem, já quando `FormOnTop` existe e formulário que envia o texto é exibido acima da `FormOnTop`, o envio falha, e o texto (mensagem) nem mesmo sai do Client.exe do meu software.

Há alguma solução para isso?

Para entender melhor, vou deixar abaixo o código que eu uso:

**Formulário que contém componente Client Socket:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  FormSender;

type
 ......

end;

 var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CS1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  StrCommand: String;
begin

    StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;

  if Pos('<|Command_From_Server|>', StrCommand) > 0 then

   begin

     FormSender.PopupMode:= pmExplicit;
     FormSender.PopupParent:= FormOnTop;
     FormSender.Show;

   end;
end;

end.
```

**Formulário que envia o texto (FormSender) e aparece acima do formulário que permanece sempre no topo:**

```
unit FormSender;

interface

uses
  Unit1;

type
 ......

end;

 var
  FormSender: TFormSender;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormSender.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

 Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);

end;

end.
```

**Formulário que permanece sempre no topo:**

OBS: A propriedade FormStyle é: `fsStayOnTop`.

```
unit FormOnTop;

        interface

        uses
          .......

        type
         ......

        end;

         var
          FormOnTop: TFormOnTop;

        implementation

        {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TFormOnTop.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    { Position form }
      Top := 0 ;
      Left := 0 ;

      { Go full screen }
      BorderStyle := bsNone ;
      WindowState  := wsmaximized;
      ClientWidth  := Screen.Width ;
      ClientHeight := Screen.Height;
      Refresh;
      SetForegroundWindow(Handle) ;
      SetActiveWindow(Application.Handle);

    end;

    procedure TFormOnTop.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
    begin
      inherited;
      if (FormStyle = fsStayOnTop) then begin
        Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
      end;
    end;

procedure TFormOnTop.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SetWindowPos(FormOnTop.handle, HWND_TOPMOST, FormOnTop.Left, FormOnTop.Top, FormOnTop.Width, FormOnTop.Height, 0);
end;


end.
```

Comment: Se comentar a linha `if Pos('<|Command_From_Server|>', StrCommand) > 0 then` aparece algo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, essa parte aí ta ok. O problema é na parte do envio: `Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);`

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu, você esta enviando e parece que não esta chegando nada é isso? Então é porque me parece que você esta usando `Pos` de maneira errada. Vou tentar formular uma resposta.

Comment: Na verdade o envio não está nem saindo do Client.exe, o problema não tem haver com o recebimento por parte do Server.exe, o código que mostrei acima é referente só a parte Client.exe :-). Esse `'<|Command_From_Server|>'` é o Server.exe quem envia para subir os Forms no Client.exe.

Comment: Entendo vou ler a sua pergunta novamente, acho que perdi algo.

Comment: Quando você diz que "nem mesmo sai", você quer dizer que a janela requisitada não aparece?

Comment: Não, nem mesmo sai o conteúdo a ser enviado :-), ou seja não envia nada.

Comment: Tá parece que você esta concentrado no possivel problema do Button, ou seja clicou no botão e nada aconteceu, é isso? Se for tente ver se minha resposta faz sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem isto:

```
StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;
```

Recebe um texto enviado por:

```
Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);
```

Então note que você escreveu `<|Hello_To_Server|>` em:

```
Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);
```

Mas aqui você solicitou `<|Command_From_Server|>` para função `Pos`:

```
if Pos('<|Command_From_Server|>', StrCommand) > 0 then
```

Até aonde entendo a função `Pos` procura uma string que contenha `<|Command_From_Server|>` e não `<|Hello_To_Server|>` e portanto o que existe dentro de:

```
   begin

     FormSender.PopupMode:= pmExplicit;
     FormSender.PopupParent:= FormOnTop;
     FormSender.Show;

   end;
```

Nunca será disparado.

Talvez você possa usar `TRegEx.IsMatch(Input, 'SUA REGEX AQUI')` ao invés de `Pos`.

Comment: Não não, você entendeu errado mesmo :-) essa parte aí que você está me falando, como falei funciona blzinha. O problema não está relacionado com strings ou recebimento de strings de referência entre Cliente.exe e Servidor.exe.

Comment: @EdejofrePRG1 Amigo acho que você não esta sabendo explicar, veja se entendi o teu código quando você clica no botão ele dispara `TFormSender.Button1Click` e o `TForm1.CS1Read` deve pegar a resposta correto?

Comment: Não essa requisição aí do `Button` vai é para o Server.exe, não fica no Client.exe não, todo esse código meu acima, é pertinente apenas a parte Client.

Comment: Amigo deixa um pouco de lado os .exe, to falando dos métodos que você criou, eu não falei nada de client ou server. Quero saber, quando você executa `Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);` ele envia o comando pra algum lugar correto? Então quem recebe ele? Seria o `StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;`? É isso?

Comment: Sim, mas o `StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;` que recebe é la no Server.exe. Pelo que eu entendi você ta pensando que é tudo no Client, mas blz, fica esclarecido aí então mesmo assim.

Comment: @EdejofrePRG1 Não eu não estou pensando isto, pelo contrario, eu entendo de cliente e servidor, e sei como funciona a comunicação deste tipo de abordagem, em nenhum momento citei client ou server, quero que você se concentre nos metodos amigo pra que possamos entender o problema juntos. Vamos pra segunda parte do problema, você disse *e o texto (mensagem) nem mesmo sai do Client.exe do meu software*, essa mensagem que você se refere é esta `Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);`?

Comment: Sim é essa daí :-)

Comment: Sugiro você fazer um exemplo prático utilizando o meu código acima para você entender melhor isso. Pegue um exemplo da internet de comunicação Cliente <--> Servidor e adapte com este meu código acima corretamente e verá o problema :-) eu só acredito em uma possível solução se for fazendo dessa forma, na prática, só analisando scripts sem testar na IDE fica complicado as vezes.

Comment: @EdejofrePRG1 Ok se é sim como você disse então chegamos a conclusão que `Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_To_Server|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);` envia pro servidor e o servidor captura usando isto `StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;` e em seguida ele verifica com `if Pos('<|Command_From_Server|>', StrCommand) > 0 then` se a string (comando) é valido. Se entendi isto, diga-me o que você digita dentro de `Edit1.Text`? É um texto comum?

Comment: Em seguida ele (**O CLIENTE**) verifica com `if Pos('<|Command_From_Server|>', StrCommand) > 0 then` se a string (comando) é valido. O texto que vai no `TEdit1` é um texto simples mesmo. Faça o que lhe falei acima, que você vai ver de fato qual é o problema :-)

Comment: Eu vou fazer um exemplo real aqui, e te mandar o link do projeto de exemplo, pra você da uma olhada.

Comment: @EdejofrePRG1 ok, se o texto enviado é simples, então independente de eu ter entendido o problema ou não, a `IF` que você criou nunca vai validar o comando `<|Hello_To_Server|>` pois ele espera `<|Command_From_Server|>`, sendo assim `Pos` irá retornar zero (`0`). Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar, mesmo que não seja o problema que você citou de fato, ainda sim parece ser um problema "a mais".

Comment: Eu ja resolvi, vlw aí kra pelo interesse em ajudar.

Comment: Se já resolveu o problema do `if Pos(` então o evento `FormSender.PopupMode:= pmExplicit;
FormSender.PopupParent:= FormOnTop;
FormSender.Show;` deve estar disparando agora né? @EdejofrePRG1

Comment: Não foi nada relacionado a isso o problema, mas o importante é que está funcionando :-)

Comment: @EdejofrePRG1 Então descobriu a causa do problema? Formule uma resposta então, isto pode ajudar outros usuários.

Answer (score 0):

O problema era um trecho de código que tem no "`FormOnTop`" e tinha esquecido de postar acima na pergunta, que é este:

```
uses
 Unit1;

    procedure TFormOnTop.TTimer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      {if FormExists(FormOnTop) then begin
        Timer2.Enabled:= True;
        Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|OK|>');
        Timer1.Enabled:= False;
      end;}
    end;

    procedure TFormOnTop.TTimer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    //ForceForegroundWindow(FormOnTop.Handle);
    end;
```

tava dando conflito por usar o mesmo Socket ("`CS1`") que o envio da mensagem e o disparo do Timer poderia conhecidir com o clique do botão de envio da mensagem, ficando ainda pior a situação :-).